# How do I customize the auto-generated comment when using .NET CodeDom Code Generation?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

I'm using `CodeCompileUnit` and `CSharpCodeProvider` to generate some source code.  It adds the header below to all generated code.  Is there a way to customize the comment so it says something else?

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3053
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. I recommend adding your own comment immediately after this one. Here's an example of how to do that: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ResourceClassGenerator.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Pretty kludgy, but when I needed to do this, I created a class that wraps the output stream and chops off the first ten lines:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the first 10 lines from the output.  This removes the junk from the .NET Code Generator.
    /// </summary>
    internal class CodeOutputHelper : TextWriter
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _Inner;
        private int _CountDown = 10;

        public CodeOutputHelper( TextWriter inner )
        {
            _Inner = inner;
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string s)
        {
            if( _CountDown-- <= 0 )
            {
                _Inner.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

        public override void Write( string value )
        {
            if (_CountDown<=0)
            _Inner.Write( value );
        }

        public override void Write( char value )
        {
            _Inner.Write( value );
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get
            {
                return _Inner.Encoding;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add your comments at the beginning of the file to look like this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// My comments
// Are go here
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3053
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just before generating the CompileUnit to a TextWriter do:

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var tw = new IndentedTextWriter(new StreamWriter(filename, false), "    ");

tw.WriteLine("//----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
tw.WriteLine("// My comments");
tw.WriteLine("// Are go here");

provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, tw, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't do it via the provided APIs in CodeDom, here's some code I just wrote to solve the issue for myself. Not perfect, but does the trick.

```
var marker = "//------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
var allTheCode = sw.ToString();
var justTheRealCode = allTheCode.Substring(allTheCode.IndexOf(marker) + marker.Length, allTheCode.LastIndexOf(marker) + marker.Length);
justTheRealCode = allTheCode.Substring(justTheRealCode.Length);
```